# integrating plugins into html and css templates

Tags: html, css, templates, plugins

I am working on a css template, which of course helps me to develop a beautiful website. I mean, good to see. Now, I am trying to integrate code from all over the web, such as, for example, a beauatiful contact form that I absolutely want in my website. The problem is that the css of the element conflicts with the css of the website and overwrites many rules.
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

could you please share the codes or the link of your site and the form? Try to write the css after the main website css. If not solved the problem then try to rewrite the classname alongside with the css. It is quite impossible to solve problem without seeing your code.

Comment: This is the plugin that I would like to implement in my website
https://colorlib.com/etc/cf/ContactFrom_v5/index.html

However, I will try your solution!

Answer (score 0):

you can add div tag surrounded in page and add a special class or id and define this class before CSS styles. actually you define the special styles for certain styles

Comment: This is the plugin that I would like to implement in my website
https://colorlib.com/etc/cf/ContactFrom_v5/index.html
Thank you for your answer, bro.